# Upload FTP file wont change on server

Tags: python, ftp, cron

I´m using cron in a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) to run a script in Python to upload a file every x minutes to my server, this file is created every x minutes from another script (which is loaded from cron every x-1 minutes). When running manually the upload.py it works well and the file is uploaded correctly, but when using cron to run *upload.py*, the uploaded file is always the same even if i delete it from the server.

Example:

-File in Raspberry Pi is 40kb or 100kb or 200kb.
-The file in Server is always 40kb. If i delete it from the server, the next time *upload.py* runs from cron, it will appear the same 40kb file even if the file in the Raspberry Pi is 100kb or 200kb.

Create file .py

```
import os
import shutil

with open("temp.dat", 'r') as fsrc:
with open("up.dat", 'w+') as fdest:    
    fsrc.seek(-324279, os.SEEK_END)
    shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdest)

fsrc.close()
fdest.close()
```

Upload .py

```
from ftplib import FTP   
HOST = 'host.com'
FTP_NAME = 'username'
FTP_PASS = 'password'

ftp = FTP(HOST)
ftp.login(FTP_NAME, FTP_PASS)
file = open('up.dat', 'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR up.dat', file)
ftp.quit()
file.close()
```

Cant understand why this happen. Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Is data in uploaded file correct ? Maybe you get 100kb file truncated to 40kb ?

Comment: It looks like to be truncated. But its all binary data, i´m still working on how to plot the data. How can i test if its uploading ok? Thanks.